# Generated JAXB object to json

Tags: json, xml, jaxb, objectmapper, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have generated JAXB classes from xsd and I have converted JAXB class to json using ObjectMapper. But in my JSON I wanted the topmost field name.  The name displayed in ObjectFactory class @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "Foo") name i-e My Json sould look something like this

```
{
"Foo":{
       "Foo_Inside": {
                      "FirstName":"abc",
                      "LastName","xyz"
                     },
      }
}
```

Below is the code I am using to convert object to json

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myJaxBObject);
```

When I have generated JAXB clasess from XSD I just have classes created till Foo_Inside. I am new to this concept, can anyone help me to generate JSON which includes the TopMost key name i-e Foo in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this will be based on an assumption because there is no xsd provided. I believe you have an xsd that looks something like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Foo" type="Foo_Inside"/>

<!-- and somewhere in the schema also have -->
<xsd:complexType name="Foo_Inside">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="blah" type="BlahType"/>
        <xsd:element name="blah-blah" type="BlahBlahType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What you need to do is remove the two specified above and replace with:

```
<xsd:element name="Foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="blah" type="BlahType"/>
            <xsd:element name="blah-blah" type="BlahBlahType" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

It will generate your Foo class as you wanted as an @XmlRootElement